# How this code can get shorter?

Tags: shell-script

Please show me how this code can get shorter:

```
find /home/peace/* -iname "*.pdf" -exec pdfgrep -i yello {} \; -exec cp {} /home/peace/Desktop/yello \;
find /home/peace/* -iname "*.pdf" -exec pdfgrep -i green {} \; -exec cp {} /home/peace/Desktop/green \;
find /home/peace/* -iname "*.pdf" -exec pdfgrep -i blue {} \; -exec cp {} /home/peace/Desktop/blue \;
find /home/peace/* -iname "*.pdf" -exec pdfgrep -i grey {} \; -exec cp {} /home/peace/Desktop/grey \;
find /home/peace/* -iname "*.pdf" -exec pdfgrep -i black {} \; -exec cp {} /home/peace/Desktop/black \;
find /home/peace/* -iname "*.pdf" -exec pdfgrep -i white {} \; -exec cp {} /home/peace/Desktop/white \;
```

Comment: what will happen when there are multiple files which contain eg. `green`? anyways it's completely pointless to a) run multiple `find` instances and b) continue to search in the file after the pattern was found, so you may experiment with something like `find /some/path -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'for f; do str=$(pdfgrep -iom1 "\<(yellow|green|blue|other_color)\>" "$f") && echo mv "$f" "/path/to/$str.pdf"; done' sh {} +`

Comment: replace `mv` with `cp` in my command above.

Comment: generalise, parameterise, then iterate.

Answer (score 0):

I can see some space for improvements.

- first parameter for find is directory, not path with "*" at the end;
- find does search inside sub-directories, so you want to restrict "find" to not search in sub-directories (find parameter "-maxdepth 1");
- restrict find results to files, because if you have directory with name "something.pdf", you may not like results (find parameter "-type f");
- cp second parameter /home/peace/Desktop/yello is a result filename? but what if pdfgrep can find "yello" in few pdf files, which one is a correct result? if "/home/peace/Desktop/yello" is a directory, you want to add "/" at the end. so I think it is a directory where we place result files.

So here we go:

```
find /home/peace/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.pdf" -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    for i in yello green blue grey black white; do
      pdfgrep -iqe "$i" "$f" &&
        cp -f "$f" "/home/peace/Desktop/$i/"
    done
  done' sh {} +
```

we also can add a check if result directory exists.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your quick and intimidating answers.

Comment: @Yurko: Regarding to your question: All files where yelllo is found shall be copied in the directory "*yello*".
And actually I made a mistake because pdfgrep does not work as I expected.
Due to no ocr possibility I have to use a other tool. This tool works:
tesseract /home/zac/Downloads/gescanntedokument/Bild.jpg beispiel -l deu
But I didn't find a search option.
Is this possible to remove pdfgrep and use tesseract (with this tool I would work with JPG files) or another ocr tool?

Comment: @sun108: of course you can use another tool instead of pdfgrep. Actually I do not have pdfgrep installed here, so I just used your command assuming it is right, later it was fixed by a person who did edit my code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
cd /home/peace || exit
set -o extendedglob # for (#i)
pdf=(*.(#i)pdf(.ND)) # all pdf files case insensitive, including hidden ones
                     # in the current directory, only considering regular files.
colors=(yello green blue grey black white)

(($#pdf)) || exit 0 # exit with success if there's no pdf file (job already done)

ret=0
for color ($colors) {
  files=(${(0)"$(pdfgrep -ilZe $color -- $pdf)"}) # all files containing the color
                                                  # using NUL-delimited records
  if (($#files)) { # some files were found
    mv -i -- $files Desktop/$color/ || ret=$? # move them, record failures
    pdf=(${pdf:|files}) # remove the files from the list as we've moved them
  }
}
exit $ret
```

That minimizes the number of invocations of `pdfgrep` and the number of times the `/home/peace` directory is being read.